# Is it possible that we can re-born in the era of Krishna again?

Tags: yuga, time

I read some answers which talk about Yuga and a day of Brahma. It is also said Yugas keep repeating.

Does it mean all avatars of Vishnu will take place again?

And if yes, is it possible any *aatma* of ours will be reborn in that era when Krishna will be living?

Comment: Yes if respective sadhanas are performed you will get be borned during krishnas time.. but here cavet the demons and evil doers also will be born along with you in order to perform there sadhana to go andhamas

Comment: It doesn't matter I'm born good or evil. In Mahabharata, there were every type of people, just like today. Sadhanas have nothing to do with it, I guess.

Comment: my apologies if you got me wrong.. Sadhana are required for anything and everything.. that be with lord extreme penance is required.. what i meant there is evil demonic triangle engulfed during krishnas time.. in mathrua Kamsa, in magadha Jarasandha, in Assam Narakasur (this are all prominent one) in taking other ausras killed by Krishna it much more Kalyayuvanaha. In addition to that kuru is with kali hamsa duryodhana.. Hamsa and dibika (salva kingdom) all this demons were there in addition sisupala.. in order to put all this to end krishna born

Comment: So you need Sadhna even to be an evil and born in same era of Krishna?

Comment: @Vikas, if everyone was born as 'good' or 'evil', then what is the need for any shastras ? If none can change, why punish someone or reward someone ? The labels 'good' and 'bad' are not permanent. They change depending on your actions i.e. sadhana